# ignore exposed filter on taxonomy combination

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view which show a list of downloads(saved as node).

And I have a exposed filter for the title, category (tax), language (tax).
Because not all files are available in native language, I would now like to achieve the following:

No matter what language is selected in the filter, all files wich are exactly the language combination DE,EN should always be visible(non DE, EN, FR or otherwise but only DE, EN)

As example:

Data:

- File1-kat1-EN
- File2-kat1-DE,EN
- FileX-kat1-DE,EN,FR

If I filter by EN, I want to see File1 and File2.

If I filter by DE, I want to see File2.

If I filter by FR, I want to see File2 and File3.

Comment: Are you using View module? If so then you can add or condition with exposed filter where you need to set fixed value to DE, EN.

Comment: I'm using the View module and I've already tried this, but get only every file with DE, EN on this conf.

Comment: Did you set second filter as OR condition(And/or, rearrange button opposite FILTER CRITERIA title in dropdown)? The other way is to append this conditon in hook_views_query_alter() but I think OR filter should work.